# On testcafe select chrome as browser and in middle of test change to emulate device to change into device view

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Hello I want use chrome to run my testcase on testcafe and after test some testcase I want change it into Emulate a Device, lets say I want change it into device Iphone X, Is it possible to change it in the middle of test? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emulate window size and portrait/landscape orientation only, you can use the `resizeWindowToFitDevice` method. See the following article:
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/resizewindowtofitdevice.html

However, if you need to emulate User Agent or touch device, you can do it only when TestCafe starts. See the following article for more details: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/concepts/browsers.html#use-chromium-device-emulation

Comment: How about If I want use my custom emulated device? how to use it? Is I just make like this?
chrome:emulation:device=Costum

Comment: TestCafe takes the device list from the [https://github.com/DevExpress/device-specs](https://github.com/DevExpress/device-specs) module. If you want to use a custom device, you can create a fork of that repository or make a PR. You will need to add a new device into the `emulated-devices.json` file.

Comment: I see, in that module can I add my own user agent string?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this line: https://github.com/DevExpress/device-specs/blob/4654b41dcf22221340e737ae93ba2dd42000e7f4/emulated-devices.json#L20